# How to write out a PNG-8888 instead of an PNG-8881?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, javax.imageio

I am attempting to read a jpg with ImageIO and then write it as a PNG after resizing the image.

Here is my code:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("/u/my.jpg"));
    BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = out.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth()/2, img.getHeight()/2, null);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(out, "png", new FileOutputStream("/u/my2.png"));
```

The problem I have is that this results in a PNG-8881 (Binary/Bitmask Alpha Layer). I want to end up with a PNG-8888 with 8 bits for alpha instead of 1 bit for alpha.

Here is Image Magick identify output:

```
Image: /u/my2.png
Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 2848x4288+0+0
Units: Undefined
Type: TrueColorAlpha
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
  red: 8-bit
  green: 8-bit
  blue: 8-bit
  alpha: 1-bit
Channel statistics:
  Red:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 252 (0.988235)
    mean: 42.2154 (0.165551)
    standard deviation: 84.6142 (0.33182)
    kurtosis: 1.41395
    skewness: 1.77533
  Green:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 252 (0.988235)
    mean: 45.1979 (0.177247)
    standard deviation: 86.0758 (0.337552)
    kurtosis: 0.935575
    skewness: 1.62013
  Blue:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 46.4455 (0.182139)
    standard deviation: 87.2088 (0.341995)
    kurtosis: 0.742603
    skewness: 1.56331
  Alpha:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 63.75 (0.25)
    standard deviation: 110.418 (0.433013)
    kurtosis: -0.666667
    skewness: -1.1547
Image statistics:
  Overall:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 81.2772 (0.318734)
    standard deviation: 92.6906 (0.363492)
    kurtosis: 0.642375
    skewness: 1.36843
Alpha: none   #00000000
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
  red primary: (0.64,0.33)
  green primary: (0.3,0.6)
  blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
  white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: white
Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: none
Interlace: None
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 2848x4288+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: Zip
Orientation: Undefined
Properties:
  date:create: 2014-01-06T12:15:38-06:00
  date:modify: 2014-01-06T12:15:38-06:00
  png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
  png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
  png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
  png:IHDR.color_type: 6 (RGBA)
  png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
  png:IHDR.width,height: 2848, 4288
  png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
  signature: f1cd61ef11890cb9981e30787ee13f9a27e0836b4b634fa7b9daf2f6bb14de66
Artifacts:
  filename: /u/my2.png
  verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 3.321MB
Number pixels: 12.21M
Pixels per second: 55.51MB
User time: 0.210u
Elapsed time: 0:01.219
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.6-6 2013-10-12 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

I need the PNG to be a 32-Bit PNG file with Full 8 bit alpha. How do I go about doing this?

Thank You.

Okay, so after reading one of the comments from @haraldK.

Updated Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("/u/my.jpg"));
    BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth()/2, img.getHeight()/2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2D = out.createGraphics();
    g2D.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth()/2, img.getHeight()/2, null);

    int w = out.getWidth();
    int h = out.getHeight();

    g2D.dispose();

    WritableRaster ras = out.getColorModel().createCompatibleWritableRaster(out.getWidth(), out.getHeight());
    BufferedImage out2 = new BufferedImage(out.getColorModel(), ras, false, null);

    ColorModel model = out.getColorModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            int data = out.getRGB(j, i);
            int pixel = model.getRGB(data);

            int a = pixel >> 24 & 0xff;
            int r = pixel >> 16 & 0xff;
            int g = pixel >> 8 & 0xff;
            int b = pixel & 0xff;

            Color color = new Color(r, g, b, a);
            if(i==25 && j==25){
                out2.setRGB(j, i, new Color(111,111,111,126).getRGB());
            }else{
                out2.setRGB(j, i, pixel);
            }

        }
    }

    ImageIO.write(out2, "png", new FileOutputStream("/u/my126.png"));

}
```

And the new output from running identify on the Image File:

```
Image: /u/my126.png
Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 1424x2144+0+0
Units: Undefined
Type: TrueColorAlpha
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
  red: 8-bit
  green: 8-bit
  blue: 8-bit
  alpha: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
  Red:
    min: 34 (0.133333)
    max: 252 (0.988235)
    mean: 168.862 (0.662203)
    standard deviation: 85.1618 (0.333968)
    kurtosis: -1.63932
    skewness: -0.419596
  Green:
    min: 42 (0.164706)
    max: 252 (0.988235)
    mean: 180.791 (0.708986)
    standard deviation: 71.5681 (0.280659)
    kurtosis: -1.51545
    skewness: -0.454524
  Blue:
    min: 44 (0.172549)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 185.782 (0.728557)
    standard deviation: 67.3447 (0.264097)
    kurtosis: -1.44714
    skewness: -0.500635
  Alpha:
    min: 126 (0.494118)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 255 (1)
    standard deviation: 0.0738282 (0.000289522)
    kurtosis: 3.05305e+06
    skewness: 1747.3
Image statistics:
  Overall:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 133.859 (0.524936)
    standard deviation: 65.0189 (0.254976)
    kurtosis: 5.00426
    skewness: -0.456343
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
  red primary: (0.64,0.33)
  green primary: (0.3,0.6)
  blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
  white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: white
Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: none
Interlace: None
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 1424x2144+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: Zip
Orientation: Undefined
Properties:
  date:create: 2014-01-06T17:08:21-06:00
  date:modify: 2014-01-06T17:08:21-06:00
  png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
  png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
  png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
  png:IHDR.color_type: 6 (RGBA)
  png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
  png:IHDR.width,height: 1424, 2144
  png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
  signature: 8bb6e37dbde980af0296dfacebff27b217360aac8994dfad8e90efeecac3bbf2
Artifacts:
  filename: /u/my126.png
  verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 3.01MB
Number pixels: 3.053M
Pixels per second: 20.35MB
User time: 0.090u
Elapsed time: 0:01.150
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.6-6 2013-10-12 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Basically this is what happens. When identify reads nothing but 255 for all alpha values - it incorrectly labels the Image File 8881, but if I change one pixel value to have an arbitrary gradient of transparency - identify recognizes the PNG File correctly as 8888.

Comment: Can you post (a link to) the image in question? It seems `identify` is wrong, and that the alpha is indeed 8 bits (if you look at the "Channel statistics", Alpa max is 255, this must be an 8 bit value).

Comment: JPG doesn't support transparency, could that have anything to do with it? Basically, you can't gain information that doesn't exist.  I suppose it could be padded to 8-bits, but then the file size would just be larger.  Then again, I guess the same could be applied for converting a JPEG to PNG in the first place.

Comment: You are correct the output of identify is incorrect because the alpha value on every single pixel in the resulting image is 255 - so this isn't a binary value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some inconsistencies in the `identify` output. This leads me to believe that `identify` is wrong (or at least isn't displaying what we would expect), and that the alpha channel in your image is indeed 8 bits (if you look at the "Channel statistics", Alpa max is 255, and 255 must be an 8 bit value).

This also seems consistent with your further debugging. So, conclusion: The image is correctly 32 bits PNG with 8 bit alpha. :-)